# In Snowflake, how can I reset first value based on timestamp?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rolling-computation

I am aware I need to write a window function but I couldn't solve the following.

My table looks like following:

```
id    timestamp 
1     01/01/2019 19:51:27
1     01/01/2019 19:58:12
1     01/01/2019 20:51:49
1     01/01/2019 22:58:19
1     01/02/2019 12:36:57
1     01/02/2019 12:47:55
1     01/02/2019 18:37:32
2     01/01/2019 09:55:05
2     01/01/2019 09:58:32
2     01/01/2019 10:08:16
2     01/01/2019 18:42:07
2     01/01/2019 19:01:15
2     01/01/2019 19:59:31
2     01/01/2019 23:51:59
```

What I would like to do is to order this by id, and timestamp, get the first value of the timestamp and scan and remove or mark rows that are within 30 minutes of this timestamp.

If the timestamp is not within 30 minutes, I would like to reset the first value to the first item we see outside of 30 minutes.

So above example, the output I want is following

```
id    timestamp              value
1     01/01/2019 19:51:27    1        <--- first value
1     01/01/2019 19:58:12    0
1     01/01/2019 20:51:49    1        <--- not within 30mins so this is new first value
1     01/01/2019 22:58:19    1        <--- not within 30mins so new first value
1     01/02/2019 12:36:57    1        <--- not within 30mins so new first value
1     01/02/2019 12:47:55    0
1     01/02/2019 18:37:32    1        <--- new group new first 
2     01/01/2019 09:55:05    1        <--- new group new first value
2     01/01/2019 09:58:32    0
2     01/01/2019 10:08:16    0
2     01/01/2019 18:42:07    1        <--- not within 30mins of first value so reset
2     01/01/2019 19:01:15    0
2     01/01/2019 19:59:31    1        <--- not within 30mins of first value so reset
2     01/01/2019 23:51:59    1        <--- not within 30mins of first value so reset
```

So technically I want to separate events that happen within 30 mins of first seen timestamp in a group, if a new row appears that's not within 30 mins of first value, I want to reset the first value and that's my new first value to start the 30 minutes window.

Tried with time diff and window functions but couldn't figure out.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Addressing a mistake on the reproducible example that FelipeHoffa caught.

Comment: This is carrying state, thus a UDTF is your best bet.

Comment: How are "01/02/2019 12:47:55    0" and "01/02/2019 18:37:32    0" within the same 30 minutes? I see a 6 hours difference

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Yes, apologies, when I was trying to create the reproducible data, I must have missed it. That would be a new reset value. you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to identify distinct sessions, of at most certain length of time.

I can solve this with a self join, and finding all the groups that start with one timestamp and fit into the next 30 minutes.

Then we eliminate the groups that are already part of a previous group:

```sql
with data as (
select regexp_substr(value, '[0-9]') id, regexp_substr(value, '     .*')::timestamp ts
from table(split_to_table($$1     01/01/2019 19:51:27
1     01/01/2019 19:58:12
1     01/01/2019 20:51:49
1     01/01/2019 22:58:19
1     01/02/2019 12:36:57
1     01/02/2019 12:47:55
1     01/02/2019 18:37:32
2     01/01/2019 09:55:05
2     01/01/2019 09:58:32
2     01/01/2019 10:08:16
2     01/01/2019 18:42:07
2     01/01/2019 19:01:15
2     01/01/2019 19:59:31
2     01/01/2019 23:51:59$$, '\n'))
), groups_30 as (
    select a.id, a.ts, array_agg(b.ts) gr30
    from data a
    left join data b
    on a.id=b.id
    and a.ts <= b.ts
    and a.ts >= timestampadd(minute, -30, b.ts)
    group by 1, 2
--    order by 1, 2 
), distinct_groups as (
    select id, ts, gr30, coalesce(lag(gr30) over(partition by id order by ts), []) gr30_prev
    from groups_30
    qualify array_intersection(gr30, gr30_prev) = []
)

select id, value::timestamp ts, iff(index=0, 1, 0)
from distinct_groups, table(flatten(gr30))
order by 1, 2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm. I got to the point of self joining and partitioning, but couldn't figure out the qualify and flattening part.